# Creating solid models from a polygon mesh using OpenCASCADE

Tags: c++, opencascade

I have a polygon mesh and I have done all the analysis to determine what surfaces I need to be able to construct a 3D model out of it.

How can I, using Open CASCADE, construct a model using information such as where planes are located or the shape of a b-spline surface?

I want to export the model as a STEP file so this isn't a visualisation task.

I have tried to look through the documentation but its not always clear whether a function does what I think it does.

Comment: Are your polygons already stored in some OCC datatypes or something different?

Comment: The mesh is taken from an STL file, but it should be irrelevant since the intention is to take information such as "draw a plane here with normal that is limited by these edges" to create a solid model.

Comment: I did not mean the type of input file (which is indeed irrelevant) but the datatypes in which the informations is stored in. If those are already OCC datatypes it may be easier to do the transition to something which can be written to STEP.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think you may have misinterpreted what I want to do. I have a feature extraction algorithm that breaks down a facet model into features (think of breaking a cube into its faces). I have fitted surfaces to this features and I would like to convert this to a STEP model. TL;DR: Facet file -> non-faceted solid model

Comment: Repeating Bowdzone's first question: are you using OCC datatypes? (Ex.: TopoDS_Face, Geom_Surface, ...). If so, the task to write them as a STEP is pretty straightforward and well documented. Please have a look here => https://www.opencascade.com/doc/occt-7.0.0/overview/html/occt_user_guides__step.html#occt_step_3

Comment: Yeah, I managed to do it in the end. I found the documentation a bit difficult to interpret at times though. I can convert a limited set of polygon meshes to solid models, I found that some of the functions to construct surfaces would fail seemingly arbitrarily. I am no longer working on the project so its not really of interest to me.